# Ethereum transactions full history

Tags: ether, etherscan

How do I retrieve the transaction history of ethereum? I want to get all transactions that include this crypto currency for specific time periods. I looked at the ethereum API, but it needs some information regarding block number and transaction index which I do not know for all the transactions. Can someone please help?

Comment: do you want all the transaction in the network or the transactions for a specific address?

Comment: In the entire blockchain. I basically want to filter them for specific time periods